# Over-writing of OpenNTF Ext Lib by IBM Upgrade Pack 1

Tags: xpages, overwrite, xpages-extlib

We have recently encountered a problem whereby an application was tested in an environment running under  OpenNTF ExtLib , but implemented in production on a server that had had OpenNTF ExtLib overwritten with the Upgrade Pack1 extension library - with the result that Xpages applications are now broken - in that some things do not work.
Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of
tell http osgi ss extlib
on the production machine?

Comment: Define "some things do not work"...

Comment: Not enough to go on, but the proper install sequence is UP1 then openntf.

Comment: Thanks Oliver - here's the out put:PRODUCTION VERSION  --> 137 RESOLVED    com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls.nl1_8.5.3.20111208-0717   140 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_8.5.3.20111208-717   - here's the TEST SERVER VERSION --->15 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.controls_8.5.3.20121022-1354   16 ACTIVE      com.ibm.xsp.extlib.core_8.5.3.20121022-1354

Comment: Thanks Tim. In particular a profile that utilises a Java Bean has stopped working - it doesn't save the profile document now.

Comment: Thanks Simon. UP1 was installed over the top of OpenNTF Extlib. We're now unable to disentangle the two installations.

Comment: If you install a newer version of Ext Lib (there are more recent 8.5.3 versions on OpenNTF), it should take precedence over UP1. That certainly works for R9.

Answer (score 0):

There are a small number of components which work differently in UP1 and ExtLib. I can't remember the details, but the release notes of UP1 may give specifics.

On your comment "a profile that utilises a Java Bean has stopped working", which Java bean? A custom one or an Extension Library one like UserBean? The key is going to be identifying what Extension Library functionality is affecting this. From what you're saying, unless I would encourage you to confirm the Extension Library is actually interfering, because unless something like UserBean is involved, it sounds like your problem is unconnected to the Extension Library.

I'd encourage using the usual steps to diagnose why the profile doesn't save - a PhaseListener to confirm it's not stopping at Validation phase, Java debugger or sysout statements to check it's going into the bean, error handling like OpenLog to confirm it's not hitting an error, and checking the obvious like access to update the profile. (And I say the latter from bitter recent experience, where I was using an app as Anonymous with Author access and trying to save a document that did not have an Authors field!)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - there were problems with posting comments on the forum, but things appear to be back to normal.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Paul - there were problems with posting comments on the forum, but things appear to be back to normal. The bean in question is a custom managed bean for saving a profile document. I have inserted sysout statements which indicate that some of the bean methods are being called on the broken production version - ie the debug output is different from that on the working development version - for identical code. Note that I fell foul of the 5 minute edit rule in the above edit.

Comment: Sounds like you're a big step forward in identifying the cause, if the debug output is different.